# Graphing connections per second in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have an Excel 2010 file like so:

```
date       time     connections
2010-10-18 08:20:00 38
2010-10-18 08:20:01 71
2010-10-18 08:20:02 67
```

I want a line graph with the number of connections as the y axis and the second as the x axis.

Comment: It looks like you need another column, which calculates the difference between the values in the `connections` column. So the values would be 38, 33, -4. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I want a line graph with the number of connections as the y axis and the second as the x axis. Do I need the difference from one second to the next to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of your **data** to something like `dd:mm:ss`, then change the format of the **X-axis** on the line graph to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`.

It seems that if the data has the date in it, that gets used as the X-axis scale rather than the time.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your column title that you have the date and time in separate columns. To graph the connections per second over more than one day you will need to merge the date and time into a single datetime value. The simplest way to do that is simply add the the date and time together in another column (assuming your date and time data is correctly formatted and Excel is interpreting them as such).